# Listing all rows that have a duplicate entry in a particular column in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

Despite a good deal of searching I haven't come up with the correct method of listing all columns for rows that have the same content in a particular column (let's say the column 'Name').

So if my table, called USERS, had the following content:

```
ID      User      Name

1       Nick      Nick
2       NickP     Nick
3       NickC     Nick
4       John      John
5       Brian     Brian
```

The SELECT statement should return:

```
ID      User      Name

1       Nick      Nick
2       NickP     Nick
3       NickC     Nick
```

As these are all the rows that contain the same content in column 'Name'.  How would I write this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name IN(SELECT Name FROM Users GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
```

Comment: I have the same problem, But in my table there are more than 90000 records, so this query is taking approx 8 min to execute. Could you please tell an efficient one.

Comment: For efficiency, guess you need to use PHP. I have 3000 records and searching for same blob images. The query did not success, got a time out.